# Storing related data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a forum website that I'm building myself. I'm planing to add group section into my website.

Users will be able to create groups. And manage by themselves. and then the creator should add moderators to the group.

How should I store this moderators? Should I create new table like this:

```
group_moderators
ID - GroupID - UserID
```

or should I directly insert into group table

```
ID - GroupName - Moderaters
1  -   Tech    - 5, 7, 9 (These are User IDs) then I can separate them with PHP.
```

Comment: Definitely the first one. You'll have all manner of problems if you want to use joins with the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option because it'll be easier to delete or update the mods and it''ll be eaiser to update the table if you intend to  give different powers to different  mods in future ..

For Ex

```
  ID - GroupID - UserID - Power
  1    14        1         Mod
  2    14        3         Super-Mod
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your plan:

1. if you are planning to have multiple moderators per group then you
   have to create a new table for moderators
2. if you are planning for only 1 moderator for each group then you can add a new column to the group table

**UPDATE**

Multiple IDs in 1 field is not a good idea at all, it will cause a lot of headache if you want to select, update, join, delete moderators.

Comment: not at all, consider the space that you are gonna save vs the headache that you will create for your self.